# Angular2 JQuery Plugin Integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, plugins

Though this question asked quite a few times, there is no clear answers. I am beginner in Angular2. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is it wise to integrate JQuery plugins with Angular2. Imagine a JQuery plugin like JQuery UI with no proper typings available. How to implement that in Angular 2. What are the problems of using JQuery with Angular2. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861464/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-angular-2) is already asked but answer is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

> It's clear and obvious that jQuery and
>   Angular are two different frameworks written above JavaScript. So it
>   is not recommended to use both the frameworks at same time on a single
>   project (either use jQuery or use Angular).

There are UI components available that are re-written using Angular without the dependency of jQuery. You can check [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) and [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap) which have almost all Bootstrap components written completely with Angular.

Alternatively, there is another complete UI framework for Angular based on Google's Material Design specs named [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/). Currently Angular Material for Angular 2 is in beta.

Also there are bundle of official UI [resources](https://angular.io/resources/#!#UI%20Components) that you can use and drive smoothly with Angular.