# How to use jQuery UI DateRangePicker in angular4?

Tags: angular, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have seen the demo of the [jQuery UI DateRangePicker](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/) but I did not find out how to use in angular4 because there is no package of jQuery UI DateRangePicker in angular2. Please tell us how to use in angular4. I have use angular version is:- 4.3.3

Comment: why not you are using primeng's calendar here https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jQuery Ui from NPM, check this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-ui 
you can download the ui picker js file and can use them from the project directory.
check this answer to add the js file into your view https://stackoverflow.com/a/41899261/713789

Comment: I have told us Jquery ui dateRangePicker only not all jquery ui.

Comment: @HarleenKaurArora you can download jQuery UI from here https://jqueryui.com/download/ (the parts you need) and you can load the js file that you only need in your view.

Comment: there is no module for this plugin.

Comment: de-select all and check only this https://jqueryui.com/download/#widgets/datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as per documentation there is no npm package to use this `dateRangePicker` in your angular2 app, so if you want to
use this in your project do complete the following steps.

1. Install all dependencies manually and list down all in the `.angular-cli.json` file in your app accordingly.

   ```
     <link href="jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="moment.min.js"></script>
     <script src="jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
   ```
2. On the top of component insert this lineHeight

   ```
   declare var $: any;
   ```
3. In your component's constructor call this method

   ```
   $(function() { $("#e1").daterangepicker(); });
   ```

PS: Replace id with your ID name.