# jquery.ui's function is not executing in angular component's template

Tags: javascript, angular, jquery-ui

I have the jquery-ui.js inside my angular's asset folder, I need to call the `.accordion` function from my component's template to wrap a `<div id="accordion">` with the accordion functionalities but I can't get the script to be executed.

`angular-cli.json`:

[image]

angular-cli compile error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/assets/jquery-ui.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png' in '/home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets'
resolve './images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png' in '/home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets'
  using description file: /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/package.json (relative path: ./src/assets)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/package.json (relative path: ./src/assets)
    using description file: /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/package.json (relative path: ./src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png doesn't exist
      .ts
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png.ts doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png.js doesn't exist
      as directory
        /home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png doesn't exist
[/home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png]
[/home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png.ts]
[/home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png.js]
[/home/rr7/workspace/emtv2/src/assets/images/ui-icons_444444_256x240.png]
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./src/assets/jquery-ui.css 7:25768-25815 7:25892-25939
 @ ./src/assets/jquery-ui.css
```

**a.component.html**

```
...
<div "id"="accordion">
...
</div>
..
<script>
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true
  });
</script>
```

Any help?

Comment: See here maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861464/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-angular-2

Answer (score 0):

Put it in your component's `ngAfterViewInit` method. Script tags in component templates are executed

**component.ts**

```
declare let $ :any;

ngAfterViewInit()
{
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
     });
}
```

**Note**: If you can avoid it, it's better not to use jquery with angular projects

Comment: Following you comment I get this console's error: $(...).accordion is not a function

Comment: Did you include jquery-ui's js file in your .angular-cli.json?

Comment: Yes, they are at the bottom of the corresponding array, please check the picture in my edit.

Comment: try this `import * as $ from 'jquery';`

Comment: Did you restart ng serve after addign jquery ui in your angular-cli.json?

Comment: yes, after adding jquery ui in my angular-cli, I deleted the node modules, run npm istall and ng serve then I'm getting that error.

Comment: You have jquery included twice in your scripts array. Can you remove that duplicate reference and try again?

Comment: same error, when I remove the jquery.ui.css, the error did not display, but the accordion is not working.